# ASP.NET Core hosted in a Windows Service - static files not being served (i.e. contents of /wwwroot)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, windows-services

I have an ASP.NET Core v3.1 application hosted in a Windows Service. When I run the service locally, everything works as expected. However, when I publish it and deploy it out to a server the static files (i.e. the contents of the /wwwroot folder) are not being served, e.g

[image]

My service exists on my file system like so, and the wwwroot contains all the necessary files:

[image]

As per [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#current-directory-and-content-root), I understand that the reason for this is because the working directory of the Windows service is the C:\Windows\system32 folder, which isn't a suitable place to drop the wwwroot files. How do I configure the location of the wwwroot folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Startup.cs class Configure() function, I needed to add the following:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(workingDirectoryPath, "wwwroot"))
});
```

where 'workingDirectoryPath' was an absolute path to the directory where my service executable is, e.g. "C:\MyService"